# Is it advisable to use meta keywords (2017)?

Tags: html

Is it still advisable to use meta keywords in website design? Googling around seems to suggest that they have fallen out of favor with search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes and no. Using meta tags is a good idea just in case someone is using an older browser that still uses them sometimes but most browsers are up to date. The only really important tag now would be the description tag as you can have that description published for your website when you search on google, safari, etc..

Also i believe online citation generators frequently look at meta tags so on my sites with information I prefer to add an author tag and a date tag.

**EDIT**
I just realized you were specifically asking about the keywords tag. The keywords tag is no longer used by the common search engines like google, bing, and safari.

Answer (score 2):

Google doesn't use meta keywords since 2009, and they declared there is not any reason to use them.

you can have a look [here](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2009/09/google-does-not-use-keywords-meta-tag.html) to find out the reason.

> **Q: Why doesn't Google use the keywords meta tag?**
>
> A: About a decade ago, search engines judged pages only on the content of web pages, not any so-called "off-page" factors such as the links pointing to a web page. In those days, keyword meta tags quickly became an area where someone could stuff often-irrelevant keywords without typical visitors ever seeing those keywords. Because the keywords meta tag was so often abused, many years ago Google began disregarding the keywords meta tag.